# SharePoint Online CSOM Custom App authentication stopped working

Tags: sharepoint-online, add-in, csom

: I have a sharepoint add in (provider hosted app) which was working fine until few days back stopped working and suddenly it throwing below error.
Token request failed.System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at Microsoft.IdentityModel.S2S.Protocols.OAuth2.OAuth2WebRequest.GetResponse() at Microsoft.IdentityModel.S2S.Protocols.OAuth2.OAuth2S2SClient.Issue(String securityTokenServiceUrl, OAuth2AccessTokenRequest oauth2Request)
I checked DisableCustomAppAuthentication setting and it is set to false only. Client ID and secret are valid as I am able to generate access token using REST API

Comment: just guessing, maybe the certificate used to register this provider hosted app expired?

Comment: I have used client and client secret to register the app and they are not expired. I tired with new sharepoint service principal as well and ran in to same issue.